# No module named 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric'

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

[image]

I was doing my college project and getting this error while using streamlit please help me to fix this.

i have tried reinstalling all the libraries like pandas, streamlit but it still throwing this error and i am not able to understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas `read_pickle` function instead and it should work:

```
import pandas as pd
movies_dict = pd.read_pickle('movie_dict.pkl')
```